# Ravan's Head Asymmetric?

Tags: ramayana, ravana

I am a bit confused about how Ravan looked. He had 10 heads. That's an even number. So where did his neck join? I mean the only possible way I can think of is that 4 heads , then the central head, then 5 heads(or in the reverse order). But this seems an awful violation of symmetry. Can someone clarify his appearance?

Comment: Om Jay Jagadamba